# Android sample keyboard issue

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I installed sample soft keyboard that is available in sdk, on device. i find a problem with this keyboard only in Quick search app. The problem is that, I launch the quick search app, change the keyboard from android keyboard to sample soft keyboard. Then again when i long press on edit text and choose to change input method, the input method picker dialog goes behind the keyboard and keyboard sits on top of that. from this point I can never hide the keyboard, it will remain on screen forever until I force stop it.
Can u guys explain what might be the problem with the sample soft keyboard?

update:  found that onCreate(), onIniatiseInterface(), onCreateInputView() and onStartInputView() methods of IME service is called twice.. looks like service is instantiated twice.. any idead why is this?

Comment: I am wondering the same thing. I use android 2.2 SDK and try to create my own softkeyboard. I have tested my softkeyboard on quick search bar and messaging app. I get two calls for onCreateInputView() and onStartInputView() also. This is problematic because my softkeyboard is heavy (uses handwriting and has big data models) and two calls will double the loading time.